# Estrutura e materiais sobre arquivos HDF5

Tags: hdf5

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe de livros e materiais sobre HDF5, além dos presentes no próprio site.

Comment: [Criei a tag pra você](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/hdf5/info). Veja se precisa de mais alguma coisa.